# I want to use sqlserver dependency in maven project(jar) for jre6 which version I should use

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, java-6

I am using **jdk1.6** for maven project and I want to use **sqlserver** dependency in pom.xml file,which version of sqlserver I should write in pom file  tag of maven project. I can not change my jdk version as client is having the same environment.

Comment: There [seems not to be any version comparible with Java 6](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/), only [for java 7](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/6.4.0.jre7/)

Comment: After many fits and false starts JRE6 finally reached end of extended support in [2018](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2244851_1.html). You should try to migrate to something newer. And so should your client.

Answer (score 0):

As maven has officially stopped the support of jdk1.6 I requested client to upgrade their environment, and executed on jdk1.8. It worked on 1.8 version.